i have to count deviations, but only changes
This func needs to see deviations from zero point on int _read
this is function caught from my code which needs to work like handlebar
int mousemovex() {                // counting mouse move on Ox
  int _read = analogRead(A0);
  int _x = _read - 512;           // +/- on Ox
  if (a == _x){                   // if we don't have any changes
    _x=0;
  }
  _x=a;
  return(_x);
}

i can't see why this func returns 0
if need it, my full code
#include <Codekeys.h>
#include <EasyHID.h>
#include <HIDPrivate.h>
#include <usbconfig.h>

 

int calib = 0;  //calibration

int Xg, Xg1, a, t;

void setup() {
  HID.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
}

int mousemovex() {                // counting mouse move on Ox
  int _read = analogRead(A0);
  int _x = _read - 512;
  if (a == _x){
    _x=0;
  }
  _x=a;
  return(_x);
}

void loop() {
  HID.tick();                    //pulling HID
  Xg=mousemovex();
  Serial.print("x = "); Serial.println(Xg);   //for debug
  if (Xg > 127) {               // if x > 127px use moveLong
    Mouse.moveLong(Xg, 0);
  }else{Mouse.move(Xg, 0);}

  
}

i think that i tried everything
i cant use keyboard.h, because i have only aruino nano

mousemovex() boils down to _x = a; return a; And since a is initialized to zero and never changed afterwards, the function always returns zero. It basically doesn't do anything. What was it supposed to do?
